# Computing log of integral in terms of log of integrand

Tags: python, logarithm, integral

This question may be half computational math, half programming.

I'm trying to estimate log[\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty f(x,y)dxdy] [actually thousands of such integrals] in Python. The function f(x,y) involves some very large/very small numbers that are bound to cause overflow/underflow errors; so I'd really prefer to work with log[f(x,y)] instead of f(x,y).

Thus my question is two parts:
1) Is there a way to estimate log[\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty f(x,y)dxdy] using the log of the function instead of the function itself?
2) Is there an implementation of this in Python?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe `sympy` would work for this.

Answer (score 0):

I would be surprised if the `math` and/or `numpy` libraries or perhaps some more specific third party libraries would not be able to solve a problem like this. Here are some of their log functions:

1. `math.log(x[, base])`, `math.log1p(x)`, `math.log2(x)`, `math.log10(x)` (https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/math.html)
2. `numpy.log`, `numpy.log10`, `numpy.log2`, `numpy.log1p`, `numpy.logaddexp`, `numpy.logaddexp2` (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.math.html#exponents-and-logarithms)

Generally, Just google: "logarithm python library" and try to identify similar stackoverflow problems, which will allow you to find the right libraries and functions to try out. Once you do that, then you can follow this guide, so that someone can try to help you get from input to expected output: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)